# Getting java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 in react native

Tags: java, android, react-native

I am new to `react-native`. when I try to run my app from the `android-studio` with my phone connected via USB (debug mode enabled). `Build succeeded` & App got installed into the phone. but when I try to open the app, it `crashes` immediately. please check the screenshot for the error and java line from the debug mode.

[image]

error in debug:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.parable.rnmvp, PID: 18237
    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at com.dooboolab.RNIap.RNIapModule.onPurchasesUpdated(RNIapModule.java:517)
        at com.dooboolab.RNIap.RNIapModule$11.run(RNIapModule.java:544)
        at com.dooboolab.RNIap.RNIapModule$2.onBillingSetupFinished(RNIapModule.java:103)
        at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientImpl$BillingServiceConnection$1.run(BillingClientImpl.java:1521)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:232)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7165)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:888)
```

ArrayList.java (error block)

```
public E get(int index) {
        if (index >= size)
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index)); //line 437 (from this line it throws error)
        return (E) elementData[index];
    }
```

Please help me to fix this issue. if I need to share any extra info. please ask in the comments.

Comment: `ArrayList.java` is probably irrelevant here. `RNIapModule.onPurchasesUpdated` is much more interesting. Is that your code? Or a library that you use?

Comment: @JoachimSauer that is an node moule` "react-native-iap": "^3.3.6"`

Comment: add your codes too

Comment: @TouhidulIslam what are the files I need to add?

Comment: Try `4.0.4` version of `react-native-iap`. To install exactly version write your terminal `npm install react-native-iap@4.0.4 --save` and clean/build your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with reference to `@firats` comment & [issue](https://github.com/dooboolab/react-native-iap/issues/770) raised by someone on react-native-iap module, i tried with `react-native-iap@4.0.4`

Now, this error got fixed.